# How to accept data from HTML and send it to excel?

Tags: html, excel, vbscript

Below is the code I have. The issue is that it is not adding the fields to Excel worksheet.

```
<! DOCTYPE html>  
<Html>  
 <Head>  
  <script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">  
     Sub Sample ()  
      Dim iRow  
      Set objExcel = CreateObject ("Excel.Application")  
      Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\ARPIT SHAJU\Desktop\Church\Member.xlsx")  
      objExcel.Application.Visible = True  
      ObjWorkbook.Windows (1).Visible = True  
      Set XlSheet =objWorkbook.Sheets (1)  
      XlSheet.Activate  
      iRow = 1  
      With objExcel  
          Do while .Cells (iRow, 1).value <> ""  
              .Cells (iRow, 1).activate  
              iRow = iRow + 1  
          Loop  
             .Cells (iRow, 1).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("fname") (0).Value  
             .Cells (iRow, 2).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("surname") (0).Value  
             .Cells (iRow, 3).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("gender") (0).Value 
             .Cells (iRow, 4).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("mstatus") (0).Value
             .Cells (iRow, 5).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("dob") (0).Value
             .Cells (iRow, 6).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("doa") (0).Value
             .Cells (iRow, 7).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("baptised") (0).Value
             .Cells (iRow, 8).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("residence") (0).Value
             .Cells (iRow, 9).value=Document.GetElementsByName ("mnumber") (0).Value
             MsgBox "Data Added Successfully”, vbinformation  
             Document.GetElementsByName ("fname") (0).Value=""  
             Document.GetElementsByName ("surname") (0).Value=""  
             Document.GetElementsByName ("gender") (0).Value=""  
             Document.GetElementsByName ("mstatus") (0).Value=""  
             Document.GetElementsByName ("dob") (0).Value=""
             Document.GetElementsByName ("doa") (0).Value=""
             Document.GetElementsByName ("baptised") (0).Value=""
             Document.GetElementsByName ("residence") (0).Value=""
             Document.GetElementsByName ("mnumber") (0).Value=""


         End With  
         ObjWorkbook. Save  
         ObjWorkbook. Close  
         Set objWorkbook = Nothing  
         Set objExcel = Nothing  
         End Sub  
      </script>  
      <style type="text/css">  
         fieldset {  
            border: #00cc00 2px solid;  
        padding: 10px;  
        color: green;  
  </style>  
<body  
<form>  
<fieldset>  
  <legend>Csharpcorner</legend>  
  <center>  

     First name:<br>   
     <input type="text" name="fname" Value=""><br>  
     Surname:<br>  
     <input type="text" name="surname" Value=""><br>  
     Gender :<br>  
     <input type="text" name="gender" Value=""><br>  
     Marital Status :<br>  
     <input type="text" name="mstatus" Value=""><br> 
     Date of Birth :<br>  
     <input type="text" name="dob" Value=""><br>
     <br>  
     Marriage Date :<br>  
     <input type="text" name="doa" Value=""><br>
     Baptised :<br>  
     <input type="text" name="baptised" Value=""><br>
     Residence :<br>  
     <input type="text" name="residence" Value=""><br>
     Mobile Number :<br>  
     <input type="text" name="mnumber" Value=""><br>
     <input type="button" onclick="Sample()" value="Submit"><br>  
  </center>  
 </fieldset>  
 <form>  
 </body>  
 </html>
```

I have my Excel and notepad in the same folder. What is wrong with the code? How can I get it to add the values to the worksheet? I would like to use it without any database or server. This is an offline form for personnel purpose. Any better solution is welcome.

Comment: You should save that code as .hta file, not as "notepad".

Comment: What software are you opening that HTML in? What errors are reported on the Console in its Developer Tools?

Comment: I have saved the notepad with the extension .htm and opened it in internet explorer

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful when copying code from website.  You need to replace all the blockquotes `“”` with double quotes `"`.

---

[image: Code Snippet Image]

Comment: I changed it to double quotes still it is not working

Comment: You'll have to allow the content and possible change the security settings of your browser to allow ActiveX Objects.  I don't think that Chrome supports them anymore.  IE is your best bet.

Comment: You may want to consider creating a HTA file instead.  [VBSEdit](http://www.vbsedit.com/default.asp?adwords=2&gclid=Cj0KCQiAl8rQBRDrARIsAEW_To__h4a8zBdxmtBkq7-4AW04GtcwQraWpjDTkYaXr43qldcCY5j3KcQaAi0JEALw_wcB) comes with a very good HTA IDE.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will try that